# MY sql query to find the # status

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contain Column name Course and Status like below

```
Course    Status
---------------------------
Math      Complete
Math      Complete
Math      Complete
Science   Incomplete
Science   Complete
Science   Complete
```

I want to a MySQL query who give following result

```
Course    % Status_complete
--------------------------
Math        100%
Science     33.3%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Course,
        SUM(Status = 'Complete') / COUNT(*) * 1.0 AS STATUS_COMPLETE
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY Course
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee2eb/14)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with % symbol and ROUND()*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee2eb/13)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
SELECT  Course,
        SUM(Status = 'Complete') / COUNT(*) * 100.0 as PercentageComplete,
        SUM(Status = 'Incomplete') / COUNT(*) * 100.0 as PercentageIncomplete
FROM    CourseTable
GROUP   BY Course
```

Output :-

```
COURSE    PERCENTAGECOMPLETE    PERCENTAGEINCOMPLETE
Math             100                         0
Science        66.66667                  33.33333
```